# Mix data of multiple columns into one column

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want to combine the content of three columns into one column like in this example:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
A     1     x
B     2     Y
```

So the result is a column with 8 lines like this:

```
Result
A 1 X
A 1 Y
A 2 X
A 2 Y
B 1 X
B 1 Y
B 2 X
B 2 Y
```

I need a Google Sheets command to do it, not a Spreadsheet solution because the result values must change automatically when using the sheet.

I have already tried with `COMBINE` and `JOIN` without much success.
If, alternatively, you show me how to combine only two of the three columns, I then could combine the third one in a second step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 2 columns:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(B1:B)), CHAR(9)))
 &" "&TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1:B&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9))))
```

[image: 0]

---

## 3 columns:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(B1:B)), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1:B&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)))&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(C1:C)),CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(B1:B)), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1:B&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)))))), CHAR(9))))
```

[image]

---

## 3 columns in two steps:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(D1:D&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))
 &" "&TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(D1:D))), CHAR(9))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Your solutions create new synapses in my brain! This is something amazing. This is a good approach I think.

Comment: @oshliaer in case you need some more synapses to be created click here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125018/186471

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `A` is in A1, in Row1 and copied down to suit:

```
=offset(A$1,int((row()-1)/4),)&" "&offset(B$1,abs(iseven(int((row()-1)/2))-1),)&" "&offset(C$1,mod((row()-1),2),)
```

Comment: the output is without spaces (if it matters)

Answer (score 0):

Rotate, join, rotate, join then etc. There are no other ways to reach this. If I had such a task, I would try to multiply N matrices N-1 times.

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
  TEXTJOIN("·",TRUE,SPLIT(
    TEXTJOIN("·",TRUE,(A2:A3&" "&TRANSPOSE(B2:B3))),
    "·")&" "&C2:C3),
  "·"
)))
```